# Call a php function with a name that's partially a variable

Tags: php, class

I'd like to ask you a simple question,

I have a class with functions called:

```
somethingModule()
someotherthingModule()
otherthingsModule()
```

How can I call these functions based on a pattern? I mean something like:

```
$call = $class->{$modulename}Module($params);
```

Comment: `$call = $class->{$modulename . 'Module'}($params);`

Answer (score 5):

Create a temporary variable:

```
$tmp = $modulename . 'Module';
$call = $class->$tmp($params);
```

Or with curly brackets:

```
$call = $class->{$modulename . 'Module'}($params);
```

Comment: Works as a charm! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should look into call_user_func() and call_user_func_array(). These functions take two arguments as input. The first one is the name of the function you want to call and the second one is the arguments you want to pass to the function. In your case, you could do this:

```
$method = $modulename.'Module';
$call = call_user_func(array($class, $method), $params);
```